# How to create a Comparer from a lambda function easily?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there was a class provided in the .Net framework that implements IComparer and that can be constructed from a lambda function.
That would be useful to be able to do:

```
void SortByLength(List<string> t)
{
    t = t.OrderBy(
           s => s, 
           Comparer<string>.FromLambda((s1,s2) => s1.Length.CompareTo(s2.Length))
        ).ToList();
}
```

It would be much easier than having to define a Comparer class each time.
I know it is not complicated to create such a FromLambda method, but I was wondering if there was an existing way in the framework as I see this as being a pretty common feature.

Comment: No there is no such thing in framework but it is fairly easy to implement.

Comment: But there is something like that...

Comment: @Rafal You **were** completely right, but with the new version of the framework things have changed (see my new answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you make it that difficult?

Ordering the list by length is as simple as:

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(s => s.Length);
```

If you really need that complicated stuff, the ComparisonComparer
could help you out. Please have a look here: [Converting Comparison to icomparer](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.de/2009/04/converting-comparison-to-icomparer.html)

This is building an IComparer from a lamda or delegate!

Here is the essential code from that example

```
public class ComparisonComparer<T> : IComparer<T>  
{  
    private readonly Comparison<T> _comparison;  

    public ComparisonComparer(Comparison<T> comparison)  
    {  
        _comparison = comparison;  
    }  

    public int Compare(T x, T y)  
    {  
        return _comparison(x, y);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: That was an example. you could have something more complex that really requires a lambda

Comment: You who gave me -1... first have a look at the link please, it definitly solves the question

Comment: @MareInfinitus I don't believe it does.  It doesn't accept in a Func essentially which is what the question was after.

Comment: Somebody here doesn't seem to accept any other delegate types except Funcs and Actions :)

Comment: Mmmh, actually after thinking about it. I think Mare Infinitus is right. You can always use the OrderBy to output an int that represents the order.

Comment: In my opinion delegate or lambda opens a very wide field of possibilities. ;)

Comment: @d--b, I would like to see how would you output ints when sorting strings for example.

Comment: @Snowbear: Sorry my comment was not well formulated. and actually it wasn't even right.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are from before the release of .NET 4.5. But with the BCL of .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012), you simply say

```
Comparer<string>.Create((s1,s2) => s1.Length.CompareTo(s2.Length))
```

See the [`Comparer<T>.Create` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating additional overloads for the common methods (OrderBy, GroupBy, etc.) to take lambdas for IComparer and IEqualityComparer:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, TKey, int> comparer)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, new GenericComparer<TKey>(comparer));
    }

    private class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, T, int> comparer;

        public GenericComparer(Func<T, T, int> comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return this.comparer(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @d--b feel free to accept the answer if you find it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating things.

```
List<string> SortByLength(List<string> t) 
{ 
    return t.OrderBy( 
           s => s.Length
        ).ToList();     
}
```

Comment: yup, that's why I +1'd your answer.  However yours wasn't there when I put mine in.,

Comment: Assigning `t` to something else in a method will not matter for the caller unless the parameter is ByRef. So you must change `List<string> t` into `ref List<string> t` in your method. If you cannot use `ref`, I guess something like `var u = t.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToList(); t.Clear(); t.AddRange(u);` will work. However, a correct use of `t.Sort` is going to be more efficient. EDIT: OK, I see you simply inherit this issue in unchanged form from the question.

Comment: Yeah, just copy pasta. I changed it to a return, but definitely better options there they could do